# Trouble instancing Eq in my Relation data type

Tags: haskell

I'm stuck instancing the following:

```
data Rel a = R [(a,a)] deriving (Read, Show)

listaPares:: Rel a -> [(a,a)]
listaPares (R rel) = rel

instance Eq (Rel a) where
    x == y = ((fst $ listaPares x == fst $ listaPares y) && (snd $ listaPares x == snd $ listaPares y))
```

`Rel` is a datatype that holds a list of tuples, and the elements inside the tuples can be anything, from an integer, a char or even a list.

My method `listaPares` takes a type `Rel` and returns the list of tuples so I can manipulate the list.

Thing is I'm really stuck instancing my data type's `Eq`. What I'm doing right now is getting the first element of the x tuple and check if its identical to the first element of the y tuple and so on, but since `a` could be a list, a simple `(==)` wouldn't really work, right?

Any tips are highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you write:

```
data Rel a = R [(a,a)] deriving (Read, Show, Eq)
```

It works just fine.

As far as list equality, there is in fact an instance of `Eq a => Eq [a]`. There's also `(Eq a, Eq b) => Eq (a, b)`, which in your case could be simplified to `Eq a => Eq (a,a)`.

So if `Eq a` holds, then `Eq (a,a)`, and thus `Eq [(a,a)]` hold as well and can be derived.

In your manually written attempt, you in fact forgot the `Eq a` constraint, which is necessary for it to work at all. It doesn't really matter what `a` *is*, it could be a list, as long as the type of the element of the list also has an `Eq` instance and so on.